# What is Naruto's family tree?

Tags: naruto

I've been trying to figure out how far Naruto's heritage can be traced back. We know his parents, but seeing as we've met other Uzumakis, I figured that there might be at least some other idea of his heritage past is parents. How far/out can his family tree be traced?

Comment: Nice question though... Answer can be found on narutowikia or as @Dimitri told in detail...

Answer (score 5):

There actually is somebody who try'd to get all the main characters a place in one big family tree on [deviant art](http://ninawh94.deviantart.com/art/Naruto-quot-family-team-tree-quot-202765636) it is a bit outdated thou as it last updated in 2011.
I advice on downloading the picture as its really hard to read otherwise

Due to some quotes through out the manga there is also a theory floating around that Naruto has some blood ties with the senju clan.

We know that the first Hokage's wife is Mito Uzumaki so this does make some sense. Some of those theorys can be read on [narutobase](http://narutobase.net/forums/showthread.php?t=149212)

[image]

And one of the most commonly accept of them would be that all descend from the Uzumaki clan to begin with.

[image]

Although there are loads of theory's and tons of rumors going about, we cannot provide a definite family tree of the people beyond Naruto's parents. As most of the theory's are still only based on small quotes such as above

For a proper time line to be set up we most likely need the parental details from either Karin or Nagatos parents, as they all descend from the Uzumaki clan

**Edit:
Warning contains content shown in the manga up to chapter 670. Read with care as you might be spoiled**

Breaking news on the family tree of naruto, in chapter 670 at page 11 the sage of the six says

> You are my son Ashura's

With this and the up following pages we can confirm that Naruto is a descendant of Ashura, which is the younger brother. The creator of the Senju clan. So Naruto is in fact of the senju blood line.
And to be even more accurate, He is the reincarnation of Ashura.

Comment: you got some sources for the fact,that the Uzumaki clan would be the origins of everything? Since Obito said, "I can tell the fire of the Senju clan dwells within you",so logically, the Senju is "older" than the Uzumaki

Comment: @Rinneg4n Not a single one, it still seems to be the most commonly accepted theory roaming around the interwebs the last 1.5 year

Comment: i dont know how japanese names show their clans, if to go by the concept that people having uchiha in their names belong to uchiha clan and so on, i think this will be invalid. rikuo's name  is hagamoro otsotsuki or something. which in no way imply that he might be descendent from uzumaki.

Answer (score 1):

This is just my interpretation but from the Sage of Six Paths, the Uchiha and Senju were born. And from the Senju, the Uzumaki split off. I would suggest that the split happened very early on in the two clans' history because they share many similar traits and the manga also states that, during the present, the Uzumaki and Senju are very distantly related, meaning that the clans would have had to split early in history. This would also support why the Uzumaki express similar if not the same traits of the Senju.

The First Hokage married Mito Uzumaki. Though it is not known who the First Hokage's child is, it is clear that they (the First's child and her/his spouse) had another child, Tsunade.

If I had to guess, I would say that Kushina was no more than a cousin to Mito Uzumaki but simply received Kurama from her. And Minato came from a different family altogether.

All of this would make the first distantly related to Naruto and would make Naruto very distantly related to the Sage of Six Paths.

Comment: The first two lines of your sentence don't make sense. An edit perhaps? :)

Answer (score 1):

- Hagoromo (Senju and Uchiha)
- Hamura (Uzumaki and Hyuga)
- Ashura (Senju)
- Amaterasu (Uchiha)
- Youngest son of Hamura (Uzumaki)
- Oldest son of Hamura (Hyuga)
- Naruto

Possibility grandfather mother-side

- Uzumaki (???)
- Senju (???)

Father-side

- Namikaze
- Senju

Grandmother possibility

- Uzumaki
- Senju
- Namikaze
- Senju

For me, it is like Hashirama; Tobirama for grand-grandfather or grand-grand-uncle because Naruto and Hashirama haves some similarities.
Each other passes Hokage without being sensei.
They are both reincarnations of Ashura.
They like taking care of plants.
Tobirama said he feels his brother when Naruto team up with him.
Naruto's nature chakra is not determined because of Kurama.

Comment: Could you try to organize these into sentences? As it stands I can't really understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: That mean naruto can be a senju/uzumaki

Comment: Minato a namikaze/senju

Comment: Kushina same as naruto

Comment: Because i thinks hagoromo is with senju and uchiha but hamura is a hyuga and uzumaki

Comment: Ashura senju is naruto ancestral then hashirama too but namikaze i thinks he is not a clan because the two person who can use perfectly the raijin is tobirama and minato

Comment: Naruto chakra is not real his kurama chakra ´s is wind and fire